# Can't install app on iOS 6 after iOS 7 Xcode update

Tags: xcode, simulator

Recently I downloaded the Xcode update, and tried my app on the iOS 7 simulator, and had to change a few things as expected. I noticed that the update uninstalled the iOS 6 simulator, so I downloaded it again and the 6.1 sim runs fine it seems, until I pressed run in Xcode. It gave me an alert box simply saying "iOS simulator failed to instal the application" with an OK button. the iOS sim was on the home screen with the old version of my app before i started working on it today. Has anybody else had this problem? It didn't give me any other details. Also my deployment target os is 6.1 and pressing build results in a success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found another post that says you have to change the "Opens in" bit to Xcode 4.6 in nibs and storyboards. fixed my problem.